# How do I work with Static CSS files in Django?

Tags: html, css, django

In my project when working with CSS files, I add a link from my html document pointing to a static file.

Every-time I want to make a change to the CSS file, I go into the static folder which I specified in **STATICFILES_DIR**, and then I run the **collectstatic** command to see the change in the browser.

Is there a more efficient and quicker way of working with CSS files in Django. I am a newbie to Django so I apologise if the question is simple, however I couldn't find an answer on the web.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While in debug mode Django will collect static for you automatically. In production, this is the only way.

also, the Django docs are the best technical writing you will ever use so enjoy and get familiar with them.

Good Luck!

> Serving the files (from the docs)
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the >static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done >automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see >django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for >production.
>
> See Deploying static files for proper strategies to serve static files in >production environments.

ALSO!! Make sure you're including the static files via load static rather than hard coding it in. ex below

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), it makes all this stuff much more simple

Comment: Hi! I don't how it works internally if it that's what are you asking.
For use it, you just need to add a new middleware in the settings.py file.
Whitenoise will reload the static files automatically when you run django app locally.